# Deploying war files to tomcat 8

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat8

I'm going to deploy some JSF-Spring-Hibernate based applications to Tomcat 8. 
The way my build system is setup, the WAR itself have libraries in it and they don't use any thing like Maven.
These WAR files already are deployed and operating correctly on Tomcat 7.
But when I deploy them to Tomcat 8, I get this error: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet

Comment: what versions of java are you using?

Comment: Java version is 1.8.60

Comment: Is this the same version for Tomcat7?

Comment: Yes, this is the same version.

Comment: And you do not get a full stacktrace?

Comment: at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1135)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 ... 10 more